# What's a good beyond hello-world application to teach people iphone development

Tags: iphone

I am going to attempt to teach some iphone application development at my job, over the course of a few weeks.

I am wondering, what is a good application to create over the course that would be interesting, yet not overly complicated.

Some qualities i'm looking for are:

- Touches on many features in UIKIT
- Doesn't require too much
  implementation edge case hell
- Ideally interesting enough that
  people are motivated by the fact that
  they're making something they can
  actually use.
- Focus is on learning iphone development, programming knowledge is assumed.

I know everything that could be an interesting app, already exist in the app store. I'm not worried about creating a never before seen idea. Just something interesting that meets the above points, and does not come bundled with the device

Comment: What is the demographic of your students?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I teach iOS development and if your colleagues want a non-beginner app I have a suggestion. There are lots of services that have public APIs that are usually REST based. Some of them that come to mind are SimpleNote, Dropbox, Evernote, ArcGIS, and even Twitter. Writing an app that accesses one of these APIs in some custom manner for your organization might be a good learning app. These types of apps use a lot of common UI and data libraries. Some of the libs and concepts that could be learned are: table views, saving settings, Core Data, NSURLConnection coding or a 3rd party lib like ASIHTTPRequest, repeating operations with a timer, and UI design in general. Because there would be lots of objects in play getting a handle on memory management would also be required. I'm using this concept in my advanced iOS development course at the college where I teach. If you can write an app with all these pieces, then you can write a lot of useful apps.

Comment: Nice, +1 for mentioning ASIHTTPRequest

Answer (score 2):

This is rather simple, but you did ask for a "beyond hello world".

It's actually kind of funny because @EricK showed me this one. When I was learning, he told me to open Interface Builder and drag out UITextField and a UITextView, wire them to a view controller, and whenever you tap enter on the UITextField, it's contents show up in the UITextView. This teaches these concepts:

- Interface Builder wiring
- How to use get/set methods in Objective-C
- An NSString is not a char*.
- Introduces the delegate pattern (UITextFieldDelegate)

If your colleagues use Java, point out that a protocol is a Java interface. I forget what they're called in .NET, but I think they're still interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is another great book for beginners: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/143023024X/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0M22VGVRBQH488KCHM83&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=470938631&pf_rd_i=507846](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X) It's really up to date; it came out today.

About the app idea, you have a couple options: create something totally new, reinvent something (like Angry Birds), or to create an app that is so good it beats everything in it's class.  I haven't released an app (yet), but the last one is definitely the  hardest. I would try with the 2nd one because it is really hard to think of something that hasn't been done before.

Other than that, I can't help you with the app idea. :(

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestion, looks interesting. In terms of the learning application, i don't expect it to be original - just something that isn't built into the phone and not a game.

Answer (score -1):

I can't recommend an app idea - you need to think of that one yourself.

What I can recommend however is this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806446

I swear by it. Teaches you everything you need to know about iPhone development. By the time you finish it, you'll know all the good parts of UIKit and Objective-C back to front. From which point, you can begin to solve problems and write code on your own.

Comment: The question is what is a good application idea (does not have to be original) that would help ME teach some iOS development concepts.